# Changing vowels in a songtext

Tags: javascript, html

Here is an excerpt from the html code:

```
...
<body>
<textarea name="user_request" id ="textrequest" cols="50" rows="5">
Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass
saßen auf der Straße und erzählten sich was.
Da kam die Polizei, ei, was ist denn das?
Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass.
</textarea>
<p></p>
<select name="vowel" id="vowel" size="1">
<option>a</option>
<option>e</option>
<option>i</option>
<option>o</option>
<option>u</option>
<option>&auml;</option>
<option>&ouml;</option>
<option>&uuml;</option>
</select>
<button onclick="replace();">Replace</button>
    <div id="output" style="font-size: 12">
</div>
</body>
...
```

jscript part:

```
function replace()  {
    var textrequest = document.getElementById("textrequest").value;
    var selection = document.getElementById("vowel").value;
    var result = textrequest.replace(/ä/,"ae");
    var output = result.replace(/[aeiouöüä]+/g,selection);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output;
    }
```

What I want to do with this program is to change every vowel into an "a" for example like this:

Draa Chanasan mat dam Kantrabass
Saßan aaf dar Straßa and arzahlten sach was.
Da kam daa Palazaa, aa, was ast dann das?
Draa Chinasan mat dam Kantrabass.

It works pretty good on most part, but it does not change "ei" into "aa". It only changes the first vowel like: Drei into Dra instead of Drei into Draa. I hope my problem is somewhat understandable. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it what is the meaning of when you select replacement. What it should replace.

Comment: @fsacer when you select replace all vowel inside the songtext change into the selected one

Comment: @sudocode yes thats what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
function replace()  {
  var textrequest = document.getElementById("textrequest").value;
  var selection = document.getElementById("vocal").value;
  var parse = textrequest.replace(/[aeiouöüä]/g, selection);
  var result = "";
  var previous = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < parse.length; i++)
  {
    var char = parse[i];
    if(char != previous)
    {
      result += char;
      previous = char;
    }
    else
    {
      switch(char)
      {
        case "a":
        case "e":
        case "i":
        case "o":
        case "u":
        case "ä":
        case "ö":
        case "ü":
          break;
        default:
          result += char;
          previous = char;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("textrequest").value = result;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJWQEQ

I'm not sure if it is correct behavior. I did this from totaly different direction which may help you.

**EDIT 1:** Added the forgotten `case 'o':` and removed parsing for ä.
**EDIT 2:** Fixed the duplicates.
**EDIT 3:** Fixed the order of operations.

Comment: how do i need to change the code so that the text comes out in the <div id=output></div> below the buttons just like in my version

Comment: just change the id of everywhere you are setting the `result` or `parse` to element from `textrequest` to `output` i.e. at the bottom of each first 2 replace functions.

Comment: where exactly can you show me i cant figure it out :/

Comment: It's quite simple but I forgot to tell you that divs doesn't have `value`. But it has `innerHTML`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpmEmE

Comment: ah i see thats why it didnt worked for me i forgot about the innerHTML..anyways thanks alot have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the regex `[aeiouöüä]+`
the `+` in the end means "one or more consecutive matches"
so in `Drei` the match will be the consecutive vowels `Dr>ei<` and the match (all vowels) will replaced by `a` to replace letter by letter you should use

```
var output = result.replace(/[aeiouöüä]/g,selection);
```

Comment: nice this works. but if i want to remove the text in the textarea to replace it with a random word, now i want that it only replaces it like it does in the program i wrote for example: If i type Drei into the textarea that it changes to Dra instead of Draa when i select "a"